# Find the second instance of a particular class using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup4 to find some scores from a website, I have this so far:

```
home_team = soup.find('div', class_='tname-home').a.text
away_team = soup.find('div', class_='tname-away').a.text
for scores in soup.find_all('span', class_='scoreboard'):
    score_home = scores.text
    score_away = scores.text
    print(home_team, score_home)
    print(away_team, score_away)
```

Home team and away team are correct and display correctly. But the scores both come from the same class of 'scoreboard' with the score_home being [0] and score_away [1] (ie, home is the first instance of the class and away is the second instance).

But when I use the [1] it pops up as an error. So I am guessing I don't know where that particular array selector goes. This is my first attempt at this type of code so I am very new to this world and I thought I had it. But when I do:

```
score_away = scores[1].text
```

I get an error `return self.attrs[key]`

I looked it up and it seems to say I am doing it right... but clearly I am not.

So I am willing to bend my understanding a bit further to gain the insight I need to solve this :)

Thanks kindly.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="current-result" id="event_detail_current_result">
<span class="scoreboard">0</span><span>
<span class="scoreboard-divider">-</span>
<span class="scoreboard">1</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: I haven't uploaded anything though... so, this might be difficult currently. I am just starting out. So, I can not change the class of "scoreboard" I just need to find the first and second instance of this. The first is the home team score and the second is the away team score.

Comment: Without the URL or HTML code is hard to help you.

Comment: I can add the HTML....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get home/away score, you can use CSS selector with `:nth-child()`. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div class="match-info">
<div class="current-result" id="event_detail_current_result">
<span class="scoreboard">0</span><span>
<span class="scoreboard-divider">-</span>
<span class="scoreboard">1</span></span>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')


score_home = soup.select_one('.current-result .scoreboard:nth-child(1)').text
score_away = soup.select_one('.current-result .scoreboard:nth-child(2)').text

print(score_home, '-', score_away)
```

Prints:

```
0 - 1
```

---

If you want to get all scores for all matches, you can do it inside the loop:

```
for match in soup.select('.match-info'):
    score_home = match.select_one('.current-result .scoreboard:nth-child(1)').text
    score_away = match.select_one('.current-result .scoreboard:nth-child(2)').text
    print(score_home, '-', score_away)
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrej Kesely - this is a steep learning curve for me and this has definitely helped out a lot! Thank you!